# MKLINK vs. Junction.exe

Tags: windows-7, junction, sysinternals

[SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals) has a program [junction.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) that creates Junctions (aka. [reparse points](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), aka. symlinks) in Windows.

However, Windows also comes with a [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx) which seems to do the same thing.

Is there a significant difference?

I tend to believe that if SysInternals has their own program, they saw a deficiency in the standard MKLink program.

Comment: `Junction` was published in September 2010, according to the linked page. Likewise, the page linked for `MKLINK` has a publish date in April 2012. That would seem to strongly indicate that `Junction` was created before the `mklink` executable was added to Windows. (I haven't dug further into when each originally appeared, hence a comment rather than a full answer. If someone wants to expand on this and create a proper answer, be my guest.)

Comment: Oops!  I missed that.   It does appear that Junction pre-dates mklink.  Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Comparison

Mark Russinovich's `junction` program was designed with a specific goal in mind: create (and delete) junction points. It was maintained through the years, but no new features were added so far. The latest version was released on July 4, 2016.

As for `mklink`, it's a built-in command available in Windows Vista and later. It can create hard links, junction points, and symbolic links. A specific delete function is not provided; you can simply use the `del` or `rd` commands, depending on whether the link points to a file or a directory, respectively.

---

## A bit of history

Prior to Vista, Windows operating systems didn't provide a way to create junction points out of the box: you either had to get a copy of the official [Resource Kit](https://web.archive.org/web/20200804140757/https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=17657), use a third-party program, or write one yourself.

### 2000

The first version of the `junction` tool was released. Quoting the official website:

> Windows 2000 and higher supports directory symbolic links, where a directory serves as a symbolic link to another directory on the computer. [...]
>
> Unfortunately, Windows comes with no tools for creating junctions—you have to purchase the Win2K Resource Kit, which comes with the `linkd` program for creating junctions. I therefore decided to write my own junction-creating tool: *Junction*.
>
> <sub>Source: [Junction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction)</sub>

### 2005-06

The `mklink` command was introduced with Windows Vista during the early beta phase.

It was available since the official Beta 1 shipped on July 27, 2005. Initially it could only create symbolic links and hard links; the ability to create junction points came later with the Community Technology Preview (CTP) released on December 19, 2005.

Apparently the command went entirely unnoticed until some time later in 2006, when it was first disclosed. Here's the earliest reference I was able to find:

> You can create symbolic link in Windows Vista now.
>
> ```
> C:\test>ver
>
> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.0.5365]
>
> C:\test>mklink
> Creates a symbolic link.
>
> MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target
>  
> [...]
> ```
>
> <sub>Source: [Symbolic link in Windows Vista](https://web.archive.org/web/20160123041138/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/04/15/576568.aspx)</sub>

Also:

> **Malcolm [MSFT] (Expert):**
> **Q:** Is there a really easy way to make a symlink?
> **A:** Open CMD, and type 'mklink'.  This tool will allow you to create junctions, hardlinks and symbolic links.
>
> <sub>Source: [NTFS Beta Chat Transcript (July 12, 2006)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151106024349/http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/09/20/457811.aspx)</sub>

---

## Additional information

> A file or directory can contain a reparse point, which is a collection of user-defined data. The format of this data is understood by the application which stores the data, and a file system filter, which you install to interpret the data and process the file.
>
> For example, reparse points are used to implement NTFS file system links and the Microsoft Remote Storage Server (RSS).
>
> <sub>Source: [Reparse Points](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/reparse-points)</sub>
>
> There are three types of file links supported in the NTFS file system: hard links, junctions, and symbolic links.
>
> <sub>Source: [Hard Links and Junctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions)</sub>

### Hard links

> A hard link is the file system representation of a file by which more than one path references a single file in the same volume. [...] Any changes to that file are instantly visible to applications that access it through the hard links that reference it. However, the directory entry size and attribute information is updated only for the link through which the change was made.
>
> <sub>Source: [Hard Links and Junctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions)</sub>

### Junctions

> A junction (also called a soft link) differs from a hard link in that the storage objects it references are separate directories, and a junction can link directories located on different local volumes on the same computer.
>
> <sub>Source: [Hard Links and Junctions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/hard-links-and-junctions)</sub>
>
> Junction points can only link to directories on a local volume; junction points to remote shares are unsupported.
>
> <sub>Source: [NTFS junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)</sub>

### Symbolic links

> A symbolic link is a file-system object that points to another file system object. The object being pointed to is called the target.
>
> Symbolic links are transparent to users; the links appear as normal files or directories, and can be acted upon by the user or application in exactly the same manner.
>
> <sub>Source: [Symbolic Links](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/symbolic-links)</sub>
>
> [Symbolic links] were introduced with the modifications made to the NTFS file system with [Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista), but available through filter drivers for [Windows XP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_XP).
>
> Unlike an [NTFS junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) (available since Windows 2000), a symbolic link can also point to a file or remote [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) network path. While NTFS junction points support only absolute paths on local drives, the NTFS symbolic links allow linking using relative paths.
>
> The default security settings in Windows Vista/[Windows 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) disallow non-elevated administrators and all non-administrators from creating symbolic links.
>
> <sub>Source: [NTFS symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)</sub>

### Further reading

- [Hard link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)
- [Symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)
- [NTFS reparse point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point)
- [NTFS junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)
- [NTFS symbolic link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link)

Comment: If you are going to make a much more detailed answer than mine, you might as well mention that [NTFS Reparse Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_reparse_point) are yet another flavour.

Comment: (referring to Hard Links, to clarify)

Comment: Pure quality answer.

Comment: NB: There are "file" symbolic links (made by plain `mklink` regardless of the target type) and there are "directory" symbolic links (made by `mklink /d`). It's best to create the right type of link for the target.

Comment: I'm curious why junction.exe got updated in 2016 and why do they continue to ship it with SysInternals?  Are they against depecration?  Come to think of it, yes they are...  Probably half those tools have sufficient replacements in Windows.  Excellent detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments, `junction.exe` came out before Vista/Winserver 2008, which came with the `mklink` command.

Therefore there is no point in using it on Vista onwards.  Versions of Windows older than Vista are no longer supported anyway.

Also, `junction.exe` does not support [NTFS Symbolic Links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) (only [NTFS Junctions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)), which were introduced with Vista/WinServer 2008 and the `mlink` command.