# Symbolic link types

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

What are the differences between different types of symbolic link in Windows?

The Microsoft website tells me;

```
/d Creates a directory symbolic link. By default, mklink creates a file symbolic link. 
/h Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
/j Creates a Directory Junction.
```

I'm still none the wiser as to what the differences are between a `directory symbolic link`, a `hard link` and a `directory junction`.

Comment: Question about directory junction has already been answered:
http://superuser.com/questions/343074/directory-junction-vs-directory-symbolic-link

Answer to soft/hard links
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-symbolic-soft-and-hard-links.html

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/752580/8972

Comment: Some Microsoft articles: [Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Symbolic Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)